# Running commands on different terminals on server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I have a list of around 50 commands each command

- activates a Python environment
- sets an environment variable (which limits the number of threads the python script can use)
- and runs a python script (with `nohup`)
  which redirects output into a log file

I would like to run these 50 commands in different terminals as I am setting an environment variable with each command. Also I am running them on a server which I don't think has a gnome-terminal or other terminal emulator.

How should I be doing this? I'll accept a solution that doesn't require me to use different terminals.

Comment: But if they don't produce any output on screen, nor consume any interactive/keyboard input, there's no need for separate terminals whatsoever... Envvars are per-process, not per-terminal.

Comment: I don’t see anything in this question that has anything to do with terminals. Or ssh, for that matter.

Comment: Does `variable=unique  command... &` not work?

Comment: yeah i ended up doing what @grawity is suggesting and i think it works the environment variable is not dependent on terminals as i thought before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only reason you want a different terminal is because "*I am setting an environment variable with each command*" then I think you can just set the variable for a particular command, then run the command (in the background in this example) with:

```
variable=unique  command  ...  &
```

---

Or if you're dead set on running a bunch of different "terminals" at once, you can use [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

> tmux is a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals to be created, accessed, and controlled from a single screen.

It has many options, and a web search for `tmux guide` has over 200,000 hits, but the basics from `man tmux` appear to be

```
EXAMPLES
 To create a new tmux session running vi(1):

       $ tmux new-session vi

 Most commands have a shorter form, known as an alias.  For new-session, this
 is new:

       $ tmux new vi

 Alternatively, the shortest unambiguous form of a command is accepted.  If
 there are several options, they are listed:

       $ tmux n
       ambiguous command: n, could be: new-session, new-window, next-window

 Within an active session, a new window may be created by typing ‘C-b c’ (Ctrl
 followed by the ‘b’ key followed by the ‘c’ key).

 Windows may be navigated with: ‘C-b 0’ (to select window 0), ‘C-b 1’ (to
 select window 1), and so on; ‘C-b n’ to select the next window; and ‘C-b p’
 to select the previous window.

 A session may be detached using ‘C-b d’ (or by an external event such as
 ssh(1) disconnection) and reattached with:

       $ tmux attach-session
```

[image] Image from [A Quick and Easy Guide to tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/)